# How do I debug the Eclipse Plugin error "Plugin was unable to load class"?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, debugging

It is trying to load my TabGroup from the Debug Dialog but I get the error that it is unable to load my tab group class.

In the "details" of the error all it says is:

"org/eclipse/debug/ui/AbstractLaunchConfigurationTabGroup"

Which is the class that my TabGroup extends.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.4 and everything worked :S

Comment: You do know they just (2 months ago) released 3.6, I presume...